# In shift selection, retain the mark if it's already active

Tags: region, motion

Under [`shift-select-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html), cursor keys behave like many other text editing environments: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>motion</kbd> starts selecting (sets and activates the mark, in Emacs terms), and <kbd>motion</kbd> without <kbd>Shift</kbd> stops selecting (deactivates the mark, in Emacs terms).

So far so good, but Emacs isn't your basic editor. It has so many sophisticated motions that it isn't practical to manage a <kbd>Shift</kbd> variant for all of them.

This doesn't mesh well with commands that mark a region. For example, I type

```
foo
```

and move the cursor to the beginning, then press C-M-SPC. This results in the mark at the end of the sexp, i.e. after `foo`, and the point before the `f`. I would expect that pressing `S-right` will retain the mark and move the point. But it doesn't: since the previous command wasn't a shift-selectable command (a command with `^` in its interactive specification), pressing `S-right` at that point sets the mark before the `f`.

How can I configure Emacs so that when the mark is already set and active, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>motion</kbd> doesn't move the mark? I always have `transient-mark-mode` on, that's not a concern.

Comment: Perhaps looking at the function `handle-shift-selection` will give you some ideas -- it is `elisp`, but tied directly in to the C-source code in `callint.c`.  You can change the `elisp` function to do whatever you need.

Comment: Note that `set-mark-command` and family also have circumstances where tests are performed and the mark is activated/deactivated.  You will need to think about those circumstances when deciding to revise/rewrite `handle-shift-selection`.  A portion of the mark activation/deactivation occurs at the C-source code level depending upon whether `transient-mark-mode` is active -- also tied into C-source -- see `transient_mark_mode` within the following files
`buffer.c`; `callint.c`; `editfns.c`; `globals.h`; `insdel.c`; `keyboard.c`

Comment: One last comment -- `transient-mark-mode` is designed to be both global, and buffer-local.  This just about exhausts my one-and-one-half cents worth of contributing to this thread  :)

Comment: I'm slightly confused. If the mark is already set, won't just a plain `right` do? I only use shift if I want to activate the mark _and_ move. If the mark is already active, I just move.

Comment: Do you mean M-right instead of S-right?

Comment: @PythonNut No, I use `S-right` when I want to set/keep the mark and move, and `right` when I want to remove/leave-unset the mark and move. That's how Emacs 24 works out of the box.

Comment: @Gilles but that's not how it works out of the box, right? Otherwise, this question wouldn't exist.

Comment: @PythonNut Launch Emacs 24.x with `emacs -Q` and switch to `*scratch*`. `shift-select-mode` is enabled by default. Type `ab`, so the point is now after `b`. Press `S-left`: this sets the mark after `b` and point before `a` and activates the mark. Press `left`: this deactivates the mark and moves point before `a`. My question is about a different scenario where I use a command which doesn't have `^` in its interactive spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I've ended up using on Emacs ≥23. The end result is: if the mark isn't active on a shifted motion command, set it at the cursor's original location and activate it; if the mark is active on a non-shifted motion command, deactivate it; commands without `interactive "^"` don't affect the mark unless it's part of their normal job.

```
(defadvice handle-shift-selection
  (around handle-shift-selection-better-integration activate)
  (cond
   ((not shift-select-mode)) ;; do nothing if shift-select-mode is off
   ((eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only)
    ;; If the original mechanism is in progress, use it
    ad-do-it)
   ((and mark-active
         (not this-command-keys-shift-translated)
         (or (symbolp last-command-event)
             (eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only)))
    ;; On a non-shifted event, deactivate the mark either if it had been set
    ;; by a shift-selection command or if the event was a cursor key or
    ;; other function key.
    (deactivate-mark))
   ((and (not mark-active)
         this-command-keys-shift-translated)
    ;; On a shifted event, set the mark to the current location and activate
    ;; it..
    (push-mark nil t t))
   ;; Note that we never set the mark to the current location if it was
   ;; already active..
   ))
(setq shift-select-mode t)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution *appears* to work:

```el
(defadvice handle-shift-selection
  (around leave-mark-intact activate preactivate compile)
  (cond ((and shift-select-mode this-command-keys-shift-translated)
          (unless mark-active
            (setq transient-mark-mode
              (cons 'only
                (unless (eq transient-mark-mode 'lambda)
                  transient-mark-mode)))
            (push-mark nil nil t)))
    ((eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only)
      (setq transient-mark-mode (cdr transient-mark-mode))
      (deactivate-mark))))
```

The changes are simple. It simply does nothing if the mark is already set.

Comment: No, that's not what I want: if I type `C-M-SPC` then `left`, the mark isn't deactivated.

Comment: I like your solution, @PythonNut , thanks! If I press `C-M-SPC left` mark isn't deactivated and I expect it, that's good. But could it be enhanced in next way: if I press `C-M-SPC left` then `S-right` then `left`, it should be deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

The following mostly works, though `C-SPC` (`set-mark-command`) no longer activates the region. Probably you won't care if you like shift-selecting because `set-mark-command` doesn't really mesh conceptually with shift-selection anyway. Otherwise you can add a check for it with `(eq this-command 'set-mark-command)`.

```el
(defun simulate-shift-selection ()
  (unless (and mark-active
               (eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only))
    (setq transient-mark-mode
          (cons 'only
                (unless (eq transient-mark-mode 'lambda)
                  transient-mark-mode)))
    ;;(push-mark nil nil t)
    ))

(add-hook 'activate-mark-hook #'simulate-shift-selection)
```

Comment: This works but has undesirable side effects, such as C-SPC not activating the region which you noticed. I've adopted a different solution which doesn't affect the mark active status except for shiftable keychords.