# Making it so that cursor movement after command will deactivate region

Tags: key-bindings, hooks, region, mouse, mark

I'm overriding `double-mouse-1` to do additional stuff on top of its default behavior. To this end, I have a function that (1) does my additional stuff and then (2) calls another function, `ora-mark-like-double-mouse-1`, which simulates normal `double-mouse-1` behavior (copied from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21922/14269)).

```
(transient-mark-mode t)

(defun ora-mark-like-double-mouse-1 ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bnd (mouse-start-end (point) (point) 1)))
    (goto-char (car bnd))
    (push-mark)
    (set-mark (point))
    (goto-char (cadr bnd))

    ; The addition of this line produces a different,
    ; but also wrong effect, in which the selection vanishes
    ; immediately after appearing.
    (setq deactivate-mark t)
  )
)

(global-set-key [(double-mouse-1)] 'ora-mark-like-double-mouse-1)
```

However, this function is slightly flawed. It selects the clicked-on word as the region, but afterwards, any non-shifted cursor movement I do with the arrow keys causes the existing region to be expanded, rather than deactivated. This is different from normal `double-mouse-1` behavior. This happens even if I just bind this function directly to `double-mouse-1`, as I do in the code above (in which I have temporarily removed my own extra functionality, and I have added a call to `(setq deactivate-mark t)`, which causes the selection to vanish immediately after appearing -- which is not the correct behavior either).

Is there a way to set it so that, after calling this function, which selects a region, subsequent non-shifted cursor movement will cause the region to be deactivated?

Alternatively, if there some way to set up a hook to run after a double-click event, I wouldn't need to override and reimplement the default functionality at all. (It would also solve the problem that the linked-to function doesn't work when I double-click on the opening quote.)

Comment: Have you figured this out eventually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Region does not get deselected on move commands using \`push-mark\` from Elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36725/region-does-not-get-deselected-on-move-commands-using-push-mark-from-elisp)

Answer (score 3):

End your command with this:

```
(setq deactivate-mark  t)
```

or this:

```
(deactivate-mark)
```

`C-h v deactivate-mark`:

> **`deactivate-mark`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
>
> Documentation:
>
> If an editing command sets this to `t`, deactivate the mark afterward.
>
> The command loop sets this to `nil` before each command,
>   and tests the value when the command returns.
>
> Buffer modification stores `t` in this variable.

`C-h f deactivate-mark`:

> **`deactivate-mark`** is a compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.
>
> `(deactivate-mark &optional FORCE)`
>
> Deactivate the mark.
>
> If Transient Mark mode is disabled, this function normally does
>   nothing; but if `FORCE` is non-`nil`, it deactivates the mark anyway.
>
> Deactivating the mark sets `mark-active` to `nil`, updates the
>   primary selection according to `select-active-regions`, and runs
>   `deactivate-mark-hook`.
>
> If Transient Mark mode was temporarily enabled, reset the value
>   of the variable `transient-mark-mode`; if this causes Transient
>   Mark mode to be disabled, don’t change `mark-active` to `nil` or
>   run `deactivate-mark-hook`.

The variable and the function do not have the same effect. You can decide which effect you want/need.

Comment: Adding `(deactivate-mark)` to the end of `ora-mark-like-double-mouse-1` causes the selection to appear and then very quickly vanish entirely after I double-click on a word. I want the selection to remain until the user presses a non-shifted cursor key (as normally happens after double-clicking a word). I do have transient mark mode enabled

Comment: Did you try setting the variable? The two do not have exactly the same effect, as their doc makes clear.

Comment: Yes, tried both ways; same effect in this case.

Comment: You don't show all your code, so it's unclear what you are doing. Deactivating the mark should be the last thing that the command that is invoked as a command does. You are apparently invoking a command non-interactively from another command. Did you deactivate the mark in the command that is invoked interactively? And why are you calling `push-mark` and then immediately calling `set-mark`. Unclear (to me).

Comment: For simplicity's sake, at the moment I'm simply adding `(setq deactivate-mark t)` to the end of the `ora-mark-like-double-mouse-1` function I already show, and binding that function to `double-mouse-1`. I will re-introduce my own external functionality once I get this working. Edited original post to show this.

Comment: Provide a minimal, step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). There is no way for us to guess what might be going on otherwise. Any number of other things, from other code, might be interfering.

Comment: I am running `emacs -q --load tempfile`, where `tempfile` is a file containing only the code I put in my original post (which I have now edited to include a call to `(setq deactivate-mark t)` -- see original post). Tested on Emacs 24.5.1 and 23.1.1. Regardless, I get the same result; the selection vanishes immediately after appearing.