# Region does not get deselected on move commands using `push-mark` from Elisp

Tags: region, mark, shift-selection, transient-mark-mode

By using `shift-select-mode`, I can select some region via holding down Shift + arrow keys. When I then stop pushing Shift and press other keys the region get deselected. But this is not the case when using `push-mark` function from Elisp code - the region stays selected when I move the cursor.

Here's an example of my function to select current symbol under cursor:

```el
(defun sandric/select-symbol-under-cursor ()
  "Select symbol under cursor."
  (interactive)
  (when (not (region-active-p))
    (let (bounds pos1 pos2 mything)
      (setq bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
      (setq beginning (car bounds))
      (setq ending (cdr bounds))
      (goto-char beginning)
      (push-mark beginning t t)
      (goto-char ending))))
```

It works as expected (leaving aside little redundance with setq and not using let bounds for now), and if I place cursor on a symbol and call the function it selects the symbol at point as the region.

The problem occurs when I press the `right` arrow key afterwards. The region is not deselected - instead it expands.

How can I make cursor movements after using my command not expand/decrease the region unless the Shift key is pressed, like the usual `shift-select-mode` behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set variable **`transient-mark-mode`** to a special value: a cons with **`only`** as its car:

```el
(defun sandric/select-symbol-under-cursor ()
  "Select symbol under cursor."
  (interactive)
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (let* ((bounds     (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
           (beginning  (car bounds))
           (ending     (cdr bounds)))
      (goto-char beginning)
      (push-mark beginning t t)
      (goto-char ending)
      (setq transient-mark-mode  (cons 'only transient-mark-mode)))))
```

`C-h v transient-mark-mode` tells you:

> **`transient-mark-mode`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Permanently local in buffer `simple.el`; global value is the same.
>
> Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` if Transient Mark mode is enabled.
>
> See the command `transient-mark-mode` for a description of this minor mode.
>
> Non-`nil` also enables highlighting of the region whenever the mark is active.
>   The region is highlighted with the `region` face.
>   The variable `highlight-nonselected-windows` controls whether to highlight
>   all windows or just the selected window.
>
> Lisp programs may give this variable certain special values:
>
> - A value of `lambda` enables Transient Mark mode temporarily.
>     It is disabled again after any subsequent action that would
>     normally deactivate the mark (e.g. buffer modification).
> - A value of **`(only . OLDVAL)`** enables Transient Mark mode
>     temporarily.  After any subsequent point motion command *that is
>     not shift-translated*, or any other action that would normally
>     deactivate the mark (e.g. buffer modification), the value of
>     `transient-mark-mode` is set to `OLDVAL`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. There's always smth to learn in emacs).

Comment: @Stefan proposed an edit to change `(setq t-m-m (cons 'only t-m-m))` to `(push 'only t-m-m)`. I prefer the form I show, as it indicates more clearly that the new value is, as the doc-string, says, `(only . OLD-TRANSIENT-MARK-MODE-VALUE)`. Yes, the two are equivalent, and yes, the `push` sexp is more concise. But in the context of this Q&A, especially, I think the explicit `setq` sexp is a bit clearer.